In order to use core library desugaring, please enable multidex
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 arm64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':flutter_keyboard_visibility'.
In order to use core library desugaring, please enable multidex.

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.


BUILD FAILED in 591ms
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

